# Tight 90 degree turn for outdoor EMT

Tags: electrical, conduit

I'm looking to install some outlets in an outdoor and rain-exposed location using 1/2 inch EMT. I've found plenty of raintight couplings and box connectors, so I'm good there. But I do need to make four tight 90 degree turns and I can't seem to find any elbow or conduit body that is specifically listed as raintight. I've seen plenty of options for compression fittings, but they aren't specifically listed as raintight.

Does such a thing exist? Or is it fine to just use a compression fitting for this even if it's not specifically listed for use in a wet location?

Comment: Are you aware of the rules of running conduit like bend limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If surface mount and going around a corner we usually use conduit bodies.

I usually use LB’s the opening is on the back and they have gaskets.

It is nuts since conduit is a wet location outside but rain tight couplings are required. These are usually compression type.

For drainage, I usually drill a small hole (1/4” or less)  in the bottom of my receptacle or switch boxes outside or any place I have splices I don’t want the fitting to fill up with water.

There are short radius 90’s but I don’t remember these approved for wet locations where most LB’s are.

Comment: Threaded raintight pull elbows with gaskets do exist, although I've seen them in commercial, so they may be special order.

Comment: @k h thanks, I do stock some but the ones I have are segmented but I think I know the ones you are talking about I was not sure if they had seals thanks.

Comment: Happy to serve the empire.  Hopefully you'll find [this](https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/p/WWG36LK14?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgf70-r6f8AIVrB-tBh2TlAuREAYYAyABEgJsMPD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIgf70-r6f8AIVrB-tBh2TlAuREAYYAyABEgJsMPD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3645!3!303439909670!!!g!543437537510!) amusing.  130 bucks a pop!

Comment: Oh nevermind that one must be fancy metal.  [Normal ones are only 10 bucks](https://vallen.com/p/appleton-electric-raintight-corner-pulling-elbows-p8hisxv5d9n1).

Comment: Not just "fancy metal", @KH, stainless steel. Because everyone needs to bling their conduit runs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the conduit bodies I deal with have female threaded ports (as for Rigid), and lids with a rubber gasket.

So there you go, just use liquidtight connectors and done.

If you are expecting to find conduit bodies *specifically with liquidtight couplers built into them*, that may be your difficulty.

Also it helps to get out of the big-box store and hit up real electrical supplies, which tend to have vastly better selections on the less popular items.

Comment: Liquid tight is normally a name for liquid tight flexible conduit & flex ends.  I have never seen a liquid tight fitting for emt only rain tight / concrete tight. There are liquid tight to rain tight combination couplings would you share where you found liquid tight fittings for emt?  Note article 358 doesn’t specify liquid tight. 358.42 refers to 314.15 damp or wet locations and rain tight meet this requirement but as I mention there is no liquid tight for emt.